# Post image via FHSTwitterEngine

Tags: ios, objective-c, fhs-twitter-engine

I have used `FHSTwitter Engine` for oauth authentication as well as to post the image and text to twitter.

When I tried to send the message alone. It posted successfully but when I send it with image

```
[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]postTweet:@"test with image" withImageData:imageData];
```

it gives the Error 204 and message : Twitter successfully processed the request, but did not return any content

If anyone has some idea to post the image with text or link.

Comment: might be you test length is more then restricted length of twitter twit..?

Comment: Post tweet Length ? @NitinGohel

Comment: [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]postTweet:@"abc" withImageData:imageData]; I am passing these two params @NitinGohel

Comment: who is having the problem here?  Sudha or MinkleGarg?  or this a team issue?

Comment: Its a team issue @MichaelDautermann

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096713/getting-error-while-posting-image-using-fhstwitterengine
=>it work for me

Comment: 204 usually indicates a success, not a failure.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to compress the image, nothing else. May be twitter api doesnt allow us to post image of big size.

```
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 0.6);
```

now pass the data into your method. You can compress the image as per your convenience.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imgURl];

    NSString *strForPost=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",self.dynamicTextToPost.text,url];
    int twitCount=[strForPost length];
    int runLoop=twitCount/140;
    int remender=twitCount%140;
    if (runLoop==0) {
        runLoop=runLoop+1;
    }
    if(remender!=0){
        runLoop=+1;
    }
       dispatch_async(GCDBackgroundThread, ^{
        @autoreleasepool {
//            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
            NSString *title = nil;
            NSString *message = nil;
            NSString *subStr;
            NSString *strRemain=strForPost;
            for (int i=0; i<=runLoop; i++) {
                int j=i*140;

                NSLog(@"strRemain.length==>%d",strRemain.length);
                if (strRemain.length<140) {
                    subStr=[strRemain substringFromIndex:0];
//                    subStr=[strForPost substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(j, strRemain.length)];
                }else if(strRemain.length>140){
                    subStr=[strForPost substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(j, 140)];

                    NSLog(@"%d",j);
                    NSLog(@"%d",strForPost.length);
                    NSLog(@"%d",strRemain.length);
                    NSLog(@"%d",strForPost.length-j);
                    NSLog(@"%d",strRemain.length-j);

                   strRemain=[strForPost substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(140, strRemain.length-140)];
                }
                NSString *strShare=[self htmlEntityDecode:subStr];
                NSError *returnCode = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]postTweet:strShare];
                [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

                if (returnCode) {
                    title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error %d",returnCode.code];
                    message = returnCode.domain;
                } else {
                    title = @"Message";
                    message = @"Successfully Shared";
                }
            }
            dispatch_sync(GCDMainThread, ^{
                @autoreleasepool {
                    if ([message isEqualToString:@"Successfully Shared"]) {

                    }else  if ([message isEqualToString:@"Twitter successfully processed the request, but did not return any content"]) {

                    }
                    else{
                        // unable to share
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```