# Getting error while posting image using FHSTwitterEngine

Tags: ios, objective-c, fhs-twitter-engine

In my app i integrated FHSTwitterEngine for posting images in twitter. Till last week it is working fine. But all of a sudden, while trying to post an image it is showing 204 Error

**Domain=FHSErrorDomain Code=204 "The request did not return any content."**

i don't think that it is an issue with duplicate post, because image will change according to user selection and while trying to post image first time itself it is giving the error.

Text based tweets are working properly. problem is with image posting only

**code i am using**

```
dispatch_async(GCDBackgroundThread, ^{
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSError *returnCode = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]postTweet:self.textToTweet withImageData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(tweetImg)];

        NSString *title = nil;
        NSString *message = nil;

        if (returnCode) {
            NSLog("Error-->%d",returnCode.code);               
        } else {
            title = @"Tweet Posted";
            message = @"Successfully";
        }
     }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a malformed multipart form data problem.

Take a look at FHSTwitterEngine.m.

Look for these lines

```
- (NSError *)sendPOSTRequestForURL:(NSURL *)url andParams:(NSDictionary *)params
...
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n",key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];        
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:data];
```

Add these lines below it

```
if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
```

I also noticed that it has missing status params bug.
Look for

```
- (NSError *)postTweet:(NSString *)tweetString withImageData:(NSData *)theData inReplyTo:(NSString *)irt {
...
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
params[@"media[]"] = theData;
```

And add this

```
params[@"status"] = tweetString;
```

Or you could get the fixes here:
https://github.com/alvani/FHSTwitterEngine/blob/master/FHSTwitterEngine/FHSTwitterEngine.m

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @alpha2. Posting image issue has been resolved  but now when ever i am trying to post the same image again and again it is simply posting the image instead of showing duplicate post error and also some time it is giving -1001 error code

Comment: hello @alpha2 I am using this updated code for posting string to twitter but I am getting the same error **Domain=FHSErrorDomain Code=204 "The request did not return any content."**

Comment: Hi @alpha2, What is obj in [**obj** isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]?

Comment: @arunit21 It's an id type containing NSString or NSData that will be used as http multipart field

Answer (score 0):

I was not be able to post image on Twitter, But Using this code now i am able to post the data with image to twitter.

```
https://github.com/alvani/FHSTwitterEngine
```

Simply replace your FHSTwitterEngine with this library.

its simply added some Changes or bugs in the Library

Answer (score 0):

compress the existing image using this code...

```
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 0.6);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need post the string length below then 130 characters